# Error occured while building recommendation Engine using pio build --verbose in predictionio

Tags: python, statistics, prediction, predictionio

I am trying to Integrate Predicitionio with my App. I followed the steps in [Quick start](http://docs.prediction.io/templates/recommendation/quickstart/)
I am stuck in step 5, Deploying Engine as a Service. I couldn't build the Recommendation using `pio build --verbose`. Following logs were printed when I execute `pio build --verbose`.

```
Warning: pio-env.sh was not found in /home/PredictionIO/conf. Using system environment variables instead.

=:/home/PredictionIO/PredictionIO-0.9.6/conf is probably an Apache Spark development tree. Please make sure you are using at least 1.3.0.
[INFO] [Console$] Using existing engine manifest JSON at /home/PredictionIO/PredictionIO-0.9.6/bin/MyRecommendation/manifest.json
[INFO] [Console$] Using command '/home/PredictionIO/sbt/sbt' at the current working directory to build.
[INFO] [Console$] If the path above is incorrect, this process will fail.
[INFO] [Console$] Uber JAR disabled. Making sure lib/pio-assembly-0.9.6.jar is absent.
[INFO] [Console$] Going to run: /home/PredictionIO/sbt/sbt  package assemblyPackageDependency
[DEBUG] [UpgradeCheckRunner] java.net.UnknownHostException: {e.getMessage}
[INFO] [Console$] [info] Loading project definition from /home/PredictionIO/PredictionIO-0.9.6/bin/MyRecommendation/project
[INFO] [Console$] [info] Set current project to template-scala-parallel-recommendation (in build file:/home/PredictionIO/PredictionIO-0.9.6/bin/MyRecommendation/)
[INFO] [Console$] [warn] No main class detected
[INFO] [Console$] [success] Total time: 1 s, completed Jul 27, 2016 12:20:53 PM
[INFO] [Console$] [warn] No main class detected
[INFO] [Console$] [info] Including from cache: scala-library.jar
[INFO] [Console$] [info] Checking every *.class/*.jar file's SHA-1.
[INFO] [Console$] [info] Merging files...
[INFO] [Console$] [warn] Merging 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF' with strategy 'discard'
[INFO] [Console$] [warn] Strategy 'discard' was applied to a file
[INFO] [Console$] [info] Assembly up to date: /home/PredictionIO/PredictionIO-0.9.6/bin/MyRecommendation/target/scala-2.10/template-scala-parallel-recommendation-assembly-0.1-SNAPSHOT-deps.jar
[INFO] [Console$] [success] Total time: 1 s, completed Jul 27, 2016 12:20:54 PM
[INFO] [Console$] Build finished successfully.
[INFO] [Console$] Looking for an engine...
[INFO] [Console$] Found template-scala-parallel-recommendation_2.10-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] [Console$] Found template-scala-parallel-recommendation-assembly-0.1-SNAPSHOT-deps.jar
[WARN] [Storage$] There is no properly configured data source.
[WARN] [Storage$] There is no properly configured repository.
[ERROR] [Storage$] Required repository (METADATA) configuration is missing.
[ERROR] [Storage$] There were 1 configuration errors. Exiting.
```

Please help me to figure this out.

Comment: is event server populated?  Check it with:  curl -i -X GET "http://localhost:7070/events.json?accessKey=<app key>"  Please paste some of data if it is populated.

Comment: Yes it started. [{"eventId":"30b112a8f3f54bbaae0be9ec507899e3","event":"$set","entityType":"user","entityId":"Jarvis","properties":{},"eventTime":"2014-08-31T04:56:00.000-07:53","creationTime":"2016-07-26T06:48:08.678Z"}

Comment: event should be either ->  "event" : "rate" or  "event" : "buy"  for the template you are using.

Comment: okay. I add the new data set as you request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason was 'pio' is not set as an environment variable. So I execute building engine as follows.

```
/home/PredictionIO/PredictionIO-0.9.6/bin/pio build --verbose
```

Then it works for me